# Angular 2 (v6) inline if else?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-filters

I use Angular Material Tables. And display in a table a list of columns (displayedColumns).

I need to display the "birthday" column using the "date" filter (`{{element[column] | date}}`), but let other columns as is. How do I say, if the column=="birthday" then apply the filter "date"?

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{column === 'birthday' ? (element[column] | date) : element[column]}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: can't I use something like `element[column] (column === "date") ? (| date:"short"))`

Comment: Well you have to respect the ternary operator syntax.. so no I don't see what you want more here.

Comment: I mean it works you did, but just to shorten the syntax:  only apply conditionnnaly the filter if possible (remove repeating element[column])

Comment: Not possible unless you apply the filter on the typescript side and not on the html... but it would be much cleaner ..

Comment: not sure if I know how to do it, but thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own pipe that checked `column` and displays `element` appropriately, or you can just do a ternary check:

```
{{column !== "birthday" ? element[column] : element[column] | date}}
```

Comment: is it possible to get "element[column]" out of expression in order do not repeat it?